# Matching two tables with duplicate entries in both tables using PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with four columns each. Both may contain duplicate rows. I want to store matched entries in one table, while unmatched entries in another table. 
Here is the code I am trying, But not getting the desired output.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","truck");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sqlA="select date, truckno, bagscount from vendor";
    $sqlB="select date, truckno, bagscount from truck";
    $resultA=mysqli_query($con,$sqlA);
    $resultB=mysqli_query($con,$sqlB);
    $objA= mysqli_fetch_all($resultA,MYSQLI_NUM);
    $objB= mysqli_fetch_all($resultB,MYSQLI_NUM);
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    while ($i<=(mysqli_num_rows($resultA)-1)){
        if ($objA[$i][0]=$objB[$j][0] && $objA[$i][1]=$objB[$j][1] && $objA[$i][2]=$objB[$j][2]){
            $i++;
            echo "row ". $i. " matches". $j. "<hr>";
            $j=0;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "not matched!";
            $j++;
        }


    }
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just use a JOIN and a single query ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 can you please suggest an alternate method to achieve the same result. I have to separate the unmatching rows out and write them to another table

Answer (score 1):

Finding the matched rows:

```
SELECT
    `vendor`.`date`,
    `vendor`.`truckno`,
    `vendor`.`bagscount`
FROM `vendor`
    INNER JOIN `truck`
        ON `vendor`.`date`=`truck`.`date`
            AND `vendor`.`truckno`=`truck`.`truckno`
            AND `vendor`.`bagscount`=`truck`.`bagscount`
```

Finding the rows in `vendor` that aren't in `truck`

```
SELECT
    `vendor`.`date`,
    `vendor`.`truckno`,
    `vendor`.`bagscount`
FROM `vendor`
    LEFT JOIN `truck`
        ON `vendor`.`date`=`truck`.`date`
            AND `vendor`.`truckno`=`truck`.`truckno`
            AND `vendor`.`bagscount`=`truck`.`bagscount`
WHERE
    `truck`.`date` IS NULL
```

Finding the rows in `truck` that aren't in `vendor`

```
SELECT
    `truck`.`date`,
    `truck`.`truckno`,
    `truck`.`bagscount`
FROM `truck`
    LEFT JOIN `vendor`
        ON `truck`.`date`=`vendor`.`date`
            AND `truck`.`truckno`=`vendor`.`truckno`
            AND `truck`.`bagscount`=`vendor`.`bagscount`
WHERE
    `vendor`.`date` IS NULL
```

The left joins (last two) make one assumption that the `date` is never null.

You can also do an insert to another table by just preceding the select with `INSERT INTO table_name SELECT ...{rest of select query}...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` in SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM vendor V
JOIN trucks T ON
V.key = T.key AND V.key2 = T.key2 ....
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp